# Generating key pair in iOS using SecKeyGeneratePair failed with errSecInteractionNotAllowed

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

In my app I am using `SecKeyGeneratePair` to generate RSA key pair. After releasing the app, I started to notice occasional `errSecInteractionNotAllowed` errors (currently very rare) when using this function, so far only on iOS 10 devices. It is unclear to me why the key pair generation failed, or what I should do to fix that. Also, I could not find any documentation as to why key pair generation should fail with this error.

This is the code I used to generate the key pair:

```
guard let access = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(nil,
                                                       kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly,
                                                       [],
                                                       nil) else {throw Error(description: "Failed to create access control")}

    let privateAttributes = [String(kSecAttrIsPermanent): true,
                             String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): keyTag + self.privateKeyExtension,
                             String(kSecAttrAccessControl): access] as [String : Any]
    let publicAttributes = [String(kSecAttrIsPermanent): true,
                            String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): keyTag + self.publicKeyExtension] as [String : Any]

    let pairAttributes = [String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                          String(kSecAttrKeySizeInBits): self.rsaKeySize,
                          String(kSecPublicKeyAttrs): publicAttributes,
                          String(kSecPrivateKeyAttrs): privateAttributes] as [String : Any]
    var pubKey, privKey: SecKey?
    let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(pairAttributes as CFDictionary, &pubKey, &privKey)
```

After this code, I am checking the status, and if it is not `errSecSuccess`, I am logging an error with the status returned from the function. This is where I noticed the `errSecInteractionNotAllowed` error.
So, why does key pair generation or what I could do in order to fix it?

Thanks,

Omer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this with Apple Developer Support, here is the solution:

```
 let privateAttributes = [String(kSecAttrIsPermanent): true,
                                 String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): keyTag + self.privateKeyExtension,
                                 String(kSecAttrAccessible): kSecAttrAccessibleAlways] as [String : Any]
        let publicAttributes = [String(kSecAttrIsPermanent): true,
                                String(kSecAttrApplicationTag): keyTag + self.publicKeyExtension,
                                String(kSecAttrAccessible): kSecAttrAccessibleAlways] as [String : Any]

        let pairAttributes = [String(kSecAttrKeyType): kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                              String(kSecAttrKeySizeInBits): self.rsaKeySize,
                              String(kSecPublicKeyAttrs): publicAttributes,
                              String(kSecPrivateKeyAttrs): privateAttributes] as [String : Any]
        var pubKey, privKey: SecKey?
        let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(pairAttributes as CFDictionary, &pubKey, &privKey)
```

The important part is the `kSecAttrAccessible`, choose the value that matches your needs from this [list](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/item_attribute_keys_and_values#1679100). Notice that some of the values will limit the access to the key in KeyVault.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Try to add an other protection class like `kSecAttrAccessibleAlways` to your call of [SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1394452-secaccesscontrolcreatewithflags) and test if the behavior still occurs.
2. Further define a [flag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags) for your use case instead of passing an empty array. E.g. [userPresence](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secaccesscontrolcreateflags/1392879-userpresence).

Additionally I stumbled across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723949/ios-sfhfkeychainutils-failing-sometimes-with-error-25308-errsecinteractionnot), maybe you can find some inspiration there.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, this was solved by talking with Apple support. The issue was incorrect use of the flag - it should be passed as one of the key parameters (in the array).

Comment: Hi Omer, no problem. I came across this while investigating the iOS crypto API. One question: do you mean the `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` flag? 
If there is some kind of forum thread where you discussed and solved the issue, then link it here. Maybe it will help others in the future ;)

Comment: No, sorry - it was using the apple technical support, not something that is public. I'll answer the question now and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. But you have to confess, I was pretty near to your solution with my prior answer ;)