# Launch Daemon is not able to access keychain entries

Tags: macos, azure-ad-msal, launch-daemon

I have a command line process which is calling an API and fetching tokens from keychain. When I am running this process standalone with/without sudo from terminal, it is able to access the keychain entries. Now I have converted this into a launch daemon and trying to execute it as a launch daemon then it is not able to access token and giving me the error as "Failed to read stored item from keychain (status: -25308)". I am using the below plist for creating the launch daemon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>TestAuth_SilentDaemon</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>*complete path of TestAuth_SilentDaemon*</string>  
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>admin</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Can someone please suggests what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it could be connected to the `errSecInteractionNotAllowed`.
Error -25308 is errSecInteractionNotAllowed  This usually means that you’re trying to access a keychain item that’s not accessible while the device is locked.

It's mostly described as iOS issue, but also MS docs talks that:

> On macOS 10.15+, MSAL's behavior is the same between iOS and macOS.
> MSAL uses keychain access groups for keychain sharing.

Check out that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735506/1595293

Based on the post:

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114159?answerId=351330022#351330022

Comment: Actually what I am trying here is to get access of login keychains items from the launch daemon which is running with sudo. The daemon is trying to look into System keychain and giving me the error as "Keychain item not found: 25300".

Comment: So later on I tried to impersonate it with current logged in  user using "su user_name" and trying to run the daemon without sudo. Then in that case I got this error "User interaction not allowed: 25308". Now I got surprised that it couldn't able to access the keychain items after impersonation. Ideally the same thing is happening when I am running my process standalone from terminal directly and it is able to access login keychain items.